# Jquery float right on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have got this code :

```
  <div class="footer-menu">
     <span>
         <i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-md" aria-hidden="true"></i>World
     </span>
     <span>
         <i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-md" aria-hidden="true"></i>Internet
     </span>
     <span>
         <i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-md" aria-hidden="true"></i>Travel
     </span>
     <span>
        <i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-md" aria-hidden="true"></i>Technology
     </span>
     <span>
     <i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-md" aria-hidden="true"></i>Fashion
     </span>
 </div>
```

What i want to achieve is to add class ***float-right*** in ***i*** tag when i hover over the span using jQuery . The problem is that when i hover over one span the class is added to every ***i*** tag.

```
 $( ".footer-menu span" ).hover(function() {
  $('i').addClass("float-right");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need Javascript to handle style update on hover. It's more easy to do it with CSS:

```
.footer-menu span i {
  float: left;
}
.footer-menu span:hover i {
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: Yea i was thinking about it but i want do do some sort of animation

Comment: Even with JavaScript  you can't animate float property.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$( ".footer-menu span" ).hover(function() {
  $(this).children("i").addClass("float-right");
});
```

if require hover out remove class

```
$( ".footer-menu span" ).hover(function() {
      $(this).children("i").toggleClass("float-right");
    });
```

Comment: And don't forget to remove the class when `mouseleave`

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
$( ".footer-menu span" ).hover(function() {
  $(this).find("i").addClass("float-right");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for helping!